# How to get list of dates in ascending order in .NET with MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am doing small project in VB.NET with MS Access. I am trying to get list of dates in ascending order. Hence I am using this query:

```
select billdate from invoice order by billdate asc
```

Actually There is a List of Date in MS Access Table

```
22-Oct-2014
09-Sep-2014
10-Sep-2014
01-Oct-2014
```

Using the above query, I got result like this

```
01-Oct-2014
09-Sep-2014
10-Sep-2014
22-Oct-2014
```

Its wrong. Its considering date only, not month and year.
I need result like this

```
09-Sep-2014
10-Sep-2014
01-Oct-2014
22-Oct-2014
```

What should I do? Please help me to finish this task.

Comment: What data type is `billdate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
select billdate from invoice order by CDate(billdate) asc
```

Comment: Arion... Its working.. Thank you very much.. I forgot to change datatype... Once again thank you very much